# For what value of $k$ does $\lim_{x\to \infty} [(x^\alpha+x^2)^k-x]$ have a limit? ($\alpha$ is a constant and $\alpha \ge 3)$

Tags: calculus

I tried to use L'Hopital's rule, but the power of the leading term of the numerator is larger than the power of the leading term of the denominator.

Comment: How did you try to apply l'Hopital's rule?  What was your denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are checking

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\left(x^\alpha + x^2\right)^k - x\right] \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

and are given that

$$\alpha \ge 3 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Note that

\begin{align}
\left(x^\alpha + x^2\right)^k - x & = \left[x^\alpha\left(1 + x^{2 - \alpha}\right)\right]^k - x \\
& = x^{k\alpha}\left(1 + x^{2 - \alpha}\right)^k - x \tag{3}\label{eq3}
\end{align}

From \eqref{eq2}, $2 - \alpha < 0$ so the term in the brackets will go to $1$ as $x \to \infty$. Thus, for the entire expression to have any possibility of a finite limit requires that

$$k \alpha = 1 \Rightarrow k = \cfrac{1}{\alpha} \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

since if $k$ is larger, the value in \eqref{eq3} will go to $\infty$ and, if it's smaller, it'll go to $-\infty$. As such, \eqref{eq3} becomes

\begin{align}
x^{k\alpha}\left(1 + x^{2 - \alpha}\right)^k - x & = x\left(1 + x^{2 - \alpha}\right)^k - x \\
& = x\left[\left(1 + x^{2 - \alpha}\right)^k - 1\right] \tag{5}\label{eq5}
\end{align}

Newton's generalized binomial theorem provides that

$$\left(1 + x^{2 - \alpha}\right)^k = 1 + kx^{2 - \alpha} + O\left(x^{2\left(2 - \alpha\right)}\right) \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

which then gives

$$x\left[\left(1 + x^{2 - \alpha}\right)^k - 1\right] = kx^{\left(2 - \alpha\right) + 1} + O\left(x^{2\left(2 - \alpha\right) + 1}\right) \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

Using \eqref{eq2}, we have that

$$\left(2 - \alpha\right) + 1 = 3 - \alpha \le 0 \tag{8}\label{eq8}$$

is a non-positive value. Similarly, the error term's power is

$$2\left(2 - \alpha\right) + 1 = 5 - 2\alpha \lt 0 \tag{9}\label{eq9}$$

so it's always negative and, thus, the error goes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$, so it doesn't contribute anything to the limit.

In summary, we have that for $\alpha = 3$ that the first term's $x$ power is $0$ so it becomes just $k$ and, thus,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\left(x^\alpha + x^2\right)^k - x\right] = k = \cfrac{1}{3} \tag{10}\label{eq10}$$

and for $\alpha \gt 3$ we instead have

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\left(x^\alpha + x^2\right)^k - x\right] = 0 \tag{11}\label{eq11}$$

Comment: I don't think $k=1/\alpha$ because then $x^{2/k}$ goes to infinity as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: The limit is taken as $x\to \infty$ instead of $k\to \infty$.

Comment: I'm looking at some related solved problems. I think we can rationalize the function.

Comment: @user398843 Thanks for the feedback. I have fixed my original equation so $x→\infty$. As for $x^{2/k}$ going to infinity, that is not important as it's only part of the expression, so the entire expression is what is most important. However, as I show, the 1 possible value which might work provides a limit of $0$. I'm sorry for so many edits & mistakes, but it's getting late for me and I'm tired. Nonetheless, I believe what I am showing now is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I appreciate it.

Comment: @user398843 You are welcome. I'm glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $(x^\alpha+x^2)^k-x=x^{2k}\left(x^{\alpha-2}+1\right)^k - x=x\left[x^{2k-1}\left(x^{\alpha-2}+1\right)^k - 1\right].$
Assume we want the existence of a *finite* limit. 
Necessarily $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}x^{2k-1}\left(x^{\alpha-2}+1\right)^k = 1. \tag 1$$ This opens two cases

- $k= {1 \over 2},$ which we exclude as $x^{2k-1}=1$ and $\left(x^{\alpha-2}+1\right)^k \to \infty$
- $k<{1\over 2},$ here we have "$0\cdot\infty$". Write $(1)$ as $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\left(x^{\alpha-2}+1\right)^k}{x^{1-2k}} = 1. $$ This is only true if $\;k(\alpha-2)=1-2k$ or equivalently $\fbox{k= 1/$\alpha$}.$

This is a necessary condition and we need to check if is also sufficient. Set $k={1\over\alpha},$ then
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left[(x^\alpha+x^2)^{1\over\alpha}-x\right]=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(1+x^{2-\alpha})^{1\over\alpha}-1}{1\over x}$$ which is equal to $0$ (l'Hospital's rule). The condition ${k= 1/\alpha}$ is also sufficient.